# MySQL Query to Laravel Eloquent Query

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel Framework and I'm confused and don't know how to convert this raw SQL Query to Laravel Eloquent query.

```
SELECT * FROM skill_user, users WHERE skill_user.skill_id = 10 AND skill_user.user_id = users.id;
```

Here's my database schema :

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: study here . http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: What did you try and what problem did occur? Stackoverflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`DB::table('skill_user')
->Join('users', 'skill_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('skill_user.skill_id','=','10')
->get();`